# node --inspect does not save the changes to disc

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I am using `node` 6 with the `--inspect` flag to debug my app. I want to save the changes from Chrome Dev Tools to the disc. Pressing `CMD + S` saves the changes for live editing but not on the disc. I drag and drop my src file into the Dev Tools but I don't see any option for mapping.

Any idea why and how I can achieve it (without using the `node-inspector`) ?